# How to filter prop values from union of interfaces

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, autocomplete, union

I am trying to use props from (import) union type and use them in react component so end consumer in the final `app` can 'filter' them in autosuggestion 
 and validate.

Types:

```
export type Clothes =
  | Shirt
  | Dress
  | Pants

export interface Shirt {
  size: "M" | "S";
  name: "Shirt";
}

export interface Dress {
  size: "XS";
  name: "Dress";
}

export interface Pants {
  size: "L" | "M" | "S";
  name: "Pants";
}
```

React component:

```
export const Clothe = (props: Clothes & {className?: string}) => {
    return (
      <div className={props.className}>
        <span>{`${props.name} ${props.size}`}</span>
      </div>     
    )
}
```

Consumer app:

`<Clothe name="Shirt" size="L" />` `// this should be invalid`

`Clothe` should only have `M` and `S` as size due to the 'name', but union give me all of the sizes to choose (`L`, `M`, `S`, `XS`)

E.g. If I choose the wrong `size` and `name` props combination, it should throw a 'ts' error.

Autocompletion should also filter out `size` prop for a particular type 
 based on what `name` prop is chosen (and preferably reverse - for `size` prop to filter only all the `name`s with that size).

How to achieve that?

[fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wv23kz?embed=1&file=index.tsx)

Comment: share your code

Comment: You should post the code in the question not just a link. But from what I can see it works as expected if I copy the code locally, it gives an error if the `name` `size` combination is invalid.